# How to see all kubectl commands issued to the cluster by every user?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to see all commands issued to our Kubernetes cluster via kubectl. Is there any native way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Enable [k8s audit log](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/), use [policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/#audit-policy) for fine grain logging.